# Sending Notification using TaskTimer

Tags: android, notifications

I want to send notification at a particular date or time. i tried to implement the example explained here : http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-example-to-send-notification.html . But i get the force close error and logcat gives illegal state exception. System services not available to Activities before onCreate.

Here is my logcat:

```
   12-03 23:19:59.712: E/AndroidRuntime(4725): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
12-03 23:19:59.712: E/AndroidRuntime(4725): java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
12-03 23:19:59.712: E/AndroidRuntime(4725):     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:3526)
12-03 23:19:59.712: E/AndroidRuntime(4725):     at com.smsalarmmanager.MainActivity.triggernotificaion(MainActivity.java:79)
12-03 23:19:59.712: E/AndroidRuntime(4725):     at com.smsalarmmanager.ScheduleClass.run(ScheduleClass.java:15)
12-03 23:19:59.712: E/AndroidRuntime(4725):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
12-03 23:24:59.743: I/Process(4725): Sending signal. PID: 4725 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification myNotification;

    private final String myBlog = "http://android-er.blogspot.com/";

    Timer timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


          Timer timer = new Timer();

          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a");
        String dateString  = "Tue, Dec 3, 2013 11:15 PM";

                try {

                Date    when = sdf.parse(dateString);


                // scheduling the task

                  timer.schedule(new ScheduleClass(), when);


                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }      





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void triggernotificaion()
    {


        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                 "Notification!",
                 System.currentTimeMillis());
               Context context = getApplicationContext();
               String notificationTitle = "Exercise of Notification!";
               String notificationText = "Text For Sample Notification";
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));
               PendingIntent pendingIntent
                 = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,
                   0, myIntent,
                   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
               myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
               myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,
                  notificationTitle,
                  notificationText,
                  pendingIntent);
               notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);


    }
}
```

ScheduleClass.java:

```
public class ScheduleClass extends TimerTask {

    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ma.triggernotificaion();

    }

}
```

Can anybody please explain where am I going wrong? I tried sending sms before using the same tasktimer class and it was working fine. But unable to send notification.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you call a method of MainActivity, but your activity has not been created, only instanciated.

You should make your `triggernotificaion` method static (you may need a `Context` argument).

For example for your ScheduleClass.java

```
public class ScheduleClass extends TimerTask {
    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
    private Context context;

    private static final String myBlog = "http://android-er.blogspot.com/";

    public ScheduleClass(Context context){
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ScheduleClass.triggernotificaion(context);

    }

    public static void triggernotificaion(Context context, String myBlog){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        String notificationTitle = "Exercise of Notification!";
        String notificationText = "Text For Sample Notification";
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, notificationText, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
    }

}
```

Then, you just have to give the context when instiating ScheduleClass